# How can I run validation when my users exit textField in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-textattributes

I have a function that will check if my textField has any issues

fun hasError(textFieldLabel: String):Boolean{}

I want this function to run only when the user has finished entering text.
When the user exists the text field, we assume they're finished and I run hasError() on that field

Here is what didn't work for me

val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)

FocusDirection.Next Only moves the focus when you decide its appropriate, but doesn't listen when the user decides to move from one field to another

Modifier.onFocusChanged{}
This doesn't work because it triggers when the page loads, and calls hasError(), leaving all my textFields in an error state

I want to trigger hasError when the user exits a text field

Answer (score 2):

You can validate TextField on exit by using onFocusChanged event of Modifier

```
modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged {focusState ->
            if (!focusState.isFocused)
                //Perform validation here
        }
```

Comment: This is under the things that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here how I resolved it :

```
@Composable
fun YourCustomTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onUnFocused: (Boolean) -> Unit = {}
) {
    var isFirstFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    TextField(value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier
            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                if (isFirstFocus) {
                    isFirstFocus = false
                } else {
                    if (!focusState.isFocused)
                        onUnFocused(focusState.isFocused)
                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simple listene for edit text change value. onValueChange is called when the text is changed and the text is finished,

Comment: On value changed is not listening for when the user exits the field. You're missing the point entirely. I'm not looking to keep the error state as the user is typing